# Python - Why am I getting a ValueError here?

Tags: python, while-loop, valueerror

Ok, I want to keep prompting the user for `choice` until they enter something not 1-5, but on some options (like 2 for example), the program goes straight to the "Goodbye" after ValueError:

```
   if(genRoster(fileName, recordsDict) and fileName != ""):
        hwPts = 250
        print("Select an option: ")
        try:
            choice = int(input("1) Get lab scores \n2) Get homework scores \n3) Get midterm exam scores \n4) Get final exam scores \n5) Get overall grades\n").strip())
            while(choice > 0 and choice < 6):
                print("Name      %")
                if(choice == 1):
                    for name in recordsDict.keys():
                        print(name+"      "+str(student.getLPGrade(recordsDict[name]))+"%") # 6 spaces
                    print("Class     "+str(getLpAvg(recordsDict))+"%\n")
                elif(choice == 2):
                    for name in recordsDict.keys():
                        print(name+"      "+str(student.getHWGrade(recordsDict[name], hwPts))+"%") # 6 spaces
                    print('Class     % 1.1f' %getHwAvg(recordsDict, hwPts), "%\n")

                elif (choice == 3):
                    for name in recordsDict.keys():
                        print(name + "      " + str(student.getMTGrade(recordsDict[name])) + "%")  # 6 spaces
                    print("Class     " + str(getMtAvg(recordsDict)) + "%\n")
                elif (choice == 4):
                    for name in recordsDict.keys():
                        print(name + "      " + str(student.getFEGrade(recordsDict[name])) + "%")  # 6 spaces
                    print("Class     " + str(getFeAvg(recordsDict)) + "%\n")
                elif (choice == 5):
                    for name in recordsDict.keys():
                        print(name + "      " + str(student.getOverallGrade(recordsDict[name], hwPts)) + "%")  # 6 spaces
                    print("Class     ", str(getOvAvg(recordsDict, hwPts)), "%\n")
                print("Select an option: ")
                choice = int(input("1) Get lab scores \n2) Get homework scores \n3) Get midterm exam scores \n4) Get final exam scores \n5) Get overall grades\n"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Goodbye! 2")
    else:
        print("Goodbye!")
```

the recordsDict is a dictionary holding student objects generated by

```
def genStud(studentName, labScores, hwScores, midtermScore, finalScore):
    return studentName, {"NAME": str(studentName).strip().title(), "LP": labScores, "HW": hwScores, "MT": int(midtermScore), "FE": int(finalScore)}
```

But this shouldnt affect the choice. What is happening here?

Comment: In your except catch the value and print it. That might shine some light on what value its trying to pass.

except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

Comment: @X18PY thank you - e is invalid literal for int() with base 10: '76.0'

Comment: I'd look into the values passed into choices (line 5) and choice (line 30), if either of these receives a string with a float value ("70.00") then converting that string into an int, may cause this error. If a value is being passed like that then a possible solution would be turning it into a float first then into an int. 

It's a bit difficult for me to find a direct problem without seeing what data will pass through the code.